# Is the radial plane radial?

Tags: general-topology

A space is [radial](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000172) provided that for each $A\subseteq X$ and each $p\in \overline A$ there is a transfinite sequence $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ of points of $A$ converging to $p$. (Here $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal and can always be taken to be a regular cardinal.)

In the [Radial plane](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000175), sets $U$ are open provided for every point $x\in U$ and line $L$ passing through $x$, there exists an open subinterval $S\subseteq L$ with $x\in S\subseteq U$.

Is the radial plane radial?

Comment: I hadn't been aware of the use of "radial" to describe topological spaces with this transfinite sequence property. Possibly of interest are my comments to [Intuition behind nets](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3341824/13130).

Comment: Steven, what is $\lambda$?

Comment: @Angelo I've fixed that omission.

Comment: @Dave see e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/B9780444503558500453 for the use of this language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because names are hard and topology was a mistake. /s

Here's a better reason: in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634781/radially-open-set-topology-is-separable/3634961#3634961), Eric Wofsey points out that $\mathbb Q^2$ is dense in the radial plane, but the radial plane limit of any sequence in $\mathbb Q^2$ must be on a line segment between two points of $\mathbb Q^2$. However, there are only countably-many such line segments, and PatrickR clarifies that these cannot cover $\mathbb R^2$ (in fact, they miss a Euclidean-dense subset of $\mathbb R^2$) due to the Baire category theorem. Therefore there is a point of the radial plane $\mathbb R^2=cl(\mathbb Q^2)$ that is not the limit of any sequence from $\mathbb Q^2$. Finally, since $\mathbb Q^2$ is countable, this point cannot be the limit of any transfinite sequence either.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4785088 gives more details for the last sentence.